# QGIS Updating composer label text via python - problem with Item Properties panel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am writing a plugin that replaces the text of a composer label based on its itemID.

When I change the text of the label using:

```
item.setText("Hello World")
```

the label changes on the composer but the text in the Item Properties panel for the label doesn't, it stays as what it was originally.

If I call `item.displayText()` before and after I change the label text this returns the correct information.

How do I get the text to change in the Item Properties panel? Using qgis 1.8 and 1.9

Comment: sounds like a bug.

Comment: I have reported the bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5862

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this was fixed in QGIS 2.0. Now, calling

```
item.setText("Hello World")
```

will automatically update the text in the item properties panel too.